# 404 from Spring 4 REST endpoint

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 4 backend with REST endpoints to hit from my AngularJS front end. The problem is whenever I hit these endpoints from my front end the request returns a 404.

I looked in my application's log file when I start Tomcat, the REST url mappings are being mapped correctly to a handler by Spring. Here's the exact line showing the url I'm trying to hit is mapped.

```
2015-11-27 09:16:50,885 RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1 INFO  annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping Mapped
"{[/rest/userAccount/createAccount],methods=[POST]}" onto public
```

I've tried hitting the endpoint using a REST testing app and it returns the same thing. So it's not something that's wrong with my Angular front end. For reference, the exact endpoint I'm trying to hit is
`/gravytrack/rest/userAccount/createAccount`.

Here's my Spring configuration files:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <!-- Log4j configuration loading -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Bootstrapping context loading -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/gravytrack-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/gravytrack-services.xml
            <!--/WEB-INF/gravytrack-security.xml-->
           </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>gravytrack.root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- session management listener -->
    <!--<listener>-->
        <!--<listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>-->
    <!--</listener>-->
    <session-config>
        <!-- session times out if no activities for 30 minutes -->
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>


    <!-- defining the DispatcherServlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>gravytrack</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>gravytrack</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
      /index.html
    </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**gravytrack-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- the application context definition for the GravyTrack DispatcherServlet -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.web" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.model" />
    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.security" />-->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--<mvc:view-controller path="/dashboard" view-name="dashboard"/>-->
    <!--<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login"/>-->

    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/webjars/"/>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/messages/messages</value>
                <value>classpath:/messages/errors</value>
                <value>classpath:/jdbc.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:/gravytrack.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <!--<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">-->
        <!--<property name="order" value="0" />-->
        <!--<property name="viewClass"-->
            <!--value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />-->
        <!--<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />-->
        <!--<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />-->
    <!--</bean>-->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <list>
                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                                    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                                    <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                                </map>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy" />
                    </list>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <!-- JSON View -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />

                <!-- XML View -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                            <property name="packagesToScan">
                                <list>
                                    <value>com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.model.domain</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**UserAccountController**

```
package com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.web;

import com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.model.domain.UserAccount;
import com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.service.manager.UserAccountManager;
import com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.service.validator.CreateUserAccountValidator;
import com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.web.dto.GenericJsonDTO;
import com.gbsolutions.gravytrack.web.dto.JsonFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/userAccount")
@SessionAttributes("userAccount")
public class UserAccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/createAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)//, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public GenericJsonDTO createAccount(@RequestBody UserAccount userAccount, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory(result, "/gravytrack/dashboard");
        validator.validate(userAccount, result);

        if(!result.hasErrors()) {
            userAccountManager.createUserAccount(userAccount);
            status.setComplete();
        }
        return jsonFactory.getDto();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signIn", method = RequestMethod.POST)//, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public GenericJsonDTO signIn(@RequestBody UserAccount userAccount, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
        System.out.println("signIn entered!");
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory(result, "/gravytrack/dashboard");
        validator.validate(userAccount, result);

        if(!result.hasErrors()) {
            userAccountManager.createUserAccount(userAccount);
            status.setComplete();
        }
        return jsonFactory.getDto();
    }
}
```

This is an application that I've converted from using JSP's to Angular. So I had to modify the configuration files because it doesn't need a lot of the configuration anymore.

As you can see in the **web.xml** and **gravytrack-servlet.xml**, I've commented out some lines that I didn't think were needed anymore. I commented out any reference to Spring Security completely because I'll have to set that up once I get this working.

I've tried changing my configuration a lot of different ways but nothing seems to work. What could be causing the problem here?

Comment: > For reference, the exact endpoint I'm trying to hit is
> /gravytrack/rest/userAccount/createAccount Shouldnt it be "/rest/userAccount/createAccount" ?

Comment: Specifically, the endpoint I'm trying to hit is `https://localhost:8443/gravytrack/rest/userAccount/createAccount'. When I change it to that it becomes `https://localhost:8443/rest/userAccount/createAccount` and still returns a 404.

Comment: What is the URL of the angularjs frontend? (to see the context-path)

Comment: I access the app at `https://localhost:8443/gravytrack` which takes me to `https://localhost:8443/gravytrack/#/login`. The app shows up fine. I don't have it in the `/webapp/WEB-INF` folder. All the front end files are in the `/webapp` folder. The endpoing I'm trying to hit is at `https://localhost:8443/gravytrack/rest/userAccount/createAccount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gravytrack</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet mapping is wrong and should be /rest/* instead of two asterisks. (I suppose /gravytrack is the context path of the application)

Another thing is the duplicate `rest` URL prefix - The `DispatcherServlet` already maps to `/rest`, this is the root URL of the spring container. The controller is a sub-resource and maps again to `/rest/..` - so the resulting URL is `/rest/rest/...`.

So you need to remove the `/rest` prefix from the RequestMapping of your REST services - here it is the class level annotation on UserAccountController, it must look like `@RequestMapping("/userAccount")`

Comment: I changed it to this and it didn't work. Still 404. But I read the Servlet 3.1 specification for Tomcat 8 and you're right about that.

Comment: You are not using Servlet 3.1 - in your web.xml you define 2.4 .

Comment: I changed the `<web-app version="2.4"` part to `<web-app version="3.1"` and its still returning the same 404.

Comment: ok, could try the request with /gravytrack/rest/rest/userAccount/createAccount ?

Comment: That worked! What is causing the extra `/rest` in the URL?

Comment: The DispatcherServlet of spring is already mapped to /rest - so /rest is the root of the spring container. Every additional resource is a sub-resource of that. So you need to remove the /rest prefix from the RequestMapping of your REST Services. (class level annotation on UserAccountController - @RequestMapping("/userAccount") )

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the help on this. If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll accept it so you get the points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96387/discussion-between-burna-and-graham).